# Swift: issues coming while moving self.view upside when clicked inside a textfield

Tags: ios, swift, animation, keyboard

I am moving self.view upside when clicked inside a textfield, but that is rather than just moving self.view fully upside, changing the size of uiimageView (present above textField )everytime. The same code was working properly in objective c .

```
func viewMovedUp(movedUp: Bool)
{
        UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
        let movementDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0.3
        self.view.clipsToBounds = true
        let movement: CGFloat = (movedUp ? -screenOffset : screenOffset)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Comment: look like constraint issue.

Comment: i created whole view again still same issue.

Comment: are you getting correct screenOffset value?

Comment: yes screenoffset it correct , but that is not visible on simulator.

Comment: press 'command+1' to view clearly on simulator. Also, check my answer. is it working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IQKeyboardManager library](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

This is extremely simple to use, just import the library in your AppDelegate :

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
```

Then enable it in the didfinishLaunchingWithOptions method :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

  return true
}
```

Pros:

- You don't even have to use a scroll view
- Very easy implementation
- Automatically provides arrows to navigate between textfields

Cons:

- The newest versions don't support iOS 7 (this is barely a con to me but still I thought it's useful to mention it)

Answer (score 0):

```
func animateTextView(textView: UITextView, up: Bool) {
     let movementDistance:CGFloat = -keyboardHeight
     let movementDuration: Double = 0.3

    var movement:CGFloat = 0
    if up {
        movement = movementDistance
    }
    else {
        movement = 0.0
    }
    UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, 0, movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```